# HiveError: Box not found, but i opened the box

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I got this error when I build my app, but don't why this comes out.

main.dart

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(appDir.path);
  await Hive.openBox('dataBox');
...
}
```

later in the code, this is where the error come out.

```dart
  print("?is box open? ${Hive.box("dataBox").isOpen}"); // true
  Box box = Hive.box("dataBox");
```

Surprising thing is, that it prints out `is box open? true`, and then after a few lines have been run, then it shows this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?
```

I looked at the documents but can't find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The method `openBox` actually returns a `Box`. Try to save that variable globally and use it later. Something like:

```
var myBox = await Hive.openBox('dataBox');
```

Then, when you need to use the box:

```
await myBox.put('something', 'something else');
```

This is the suggested appproach in the [official documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/README).